# js regex extract whitespace between letters. positive lookbehind?

Tags: javascript, regex, lookbehind

I want to match the `\s` character within any letter, **not numbers**:

```
'abc def ghi'
```

should match the empty spaces between `c` and `d` & `f` and `g`.

I think I should use positive lookbehind, but as I know, it`s not posibile in js. Any solution?

Comment: What is the final output you expect? `abc<span> </span>def<span> </span>ghi`?

Comment: yes, that`s what I need

Answer (score 3):

This one should work

```
(?=[^0-9]+)(\s+)(?=[^0-9]+)
```

or another tricky way, you just replace your conditional white space by some special text first, e.g. I use `_SPACE_`

```
/([^0-9])(\s+)(?=[^0-9])/$1_SPACE_/
```

Original text:

```
abc defg xhi abc 111 999 111 abc def
```

After replacing:

```
abc_SPACE_defg_SPACE_xhi_SPACE_abc 111 999 111 abc_SPACE_def
```

Then you just search for `_SPACE_` instead of your conditional white space.

Comment: never thought of "looking ahead of nothing". great answer.

Comment: I`ve tested it, the output is null

Comment: start from `\b` is also not bad.

Comment: @GigiIonel I edited it, just put `(...)` for capturing.

Comment: I don`t understand console.log("abc abc".match('(?=[^0-9]+)\s+(?=[^0-9]+)'))

Comment: @GigiIonel I just gave you an another way above, just two step replacement. Much more better that the first one.

Comment: @GigiIonel - `'(?=[^0-9]+)\s+(?=[^0-9]+)'` is not a RegExp object. Try `console.log("abc abc".match(/(?=[^0-9]+)\s+(?=[^0-9]+)/))`

Answer (score 3):

Use this code:

```js
var s = "abc def ghi 3rt";
s = s.replace(/(^|.)(\s+)(?!\d)/g, function (m, grp1, grp2, offset, input) {
      return (grp1.length !== 0 && !((grp1.charCodeAt(0) > 47) && (grp1.charCodeAt(0) <  58))) ? grp1 + "<span>" + grp2 + "</span>" : grp1 + grp2;
});
alert(s);
```

With `(^|.)(\s+)(?!\d)`, we match any spaces (`\s+`) that are either at the start of string or after some character that we check for a digit equivalence with `(grp1.charCodeAt(0) > 47) && (grp1.charCodeAt(0) <  58)`. And `(?!\d)` makes sure we only match those spaces that are not followed with a digit.

**UPDATE**

If you literally mean to match whitespace between *English letters*, use

```js
var s = "abc def ghi 3rt";
s = s.replace(/(^|[a-z])(\s+)(?=[a-z])/ig, "$1<span>$2</span>");
document.write(s.replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g,"&gt;"));
```

Comment: Do you really mean to say *between Engish letters*? I have updated the answer. Note that in the second demo code, the initial space will also get enclosed with `span` tags. Let me know if it is not what you need.

Comment: Just FYI: if initial whitespace should not be enclosed in tags, you will have to use the callback function anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can use matched group and a lookahead:

```
var s = 'abc def ghi';
var r = s.replace(/([a-z])(\s+)(?=[a-z])/gi, "$1<span>$2</span>");
//=> "abc<span> </span>def<span> </span>ghi"
```

Comment: the problem here is that **span** matches just two times, I need one ore more :)

Comment: Sorry didn't get that comment. Aren't there only 2 such spaces surrounded by letters in the input?

Comment: the input is just an example, in my work there could be more...anyway, the best solution would be to match \s and done...if would be possible

Comment: Doesn't matter if if your input is different. This regex will work with any # of those spaces occurrences that are **between letters**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the split function

```
str = str.replace(" ", "<span> </span>");
```

and then you can use **each** function to place in tag :)

Comment: but what if there are many empty spaces? I can`t use the + operator, for one or more...

Comment: you can ignore them by using **IF**  check

Comment: but I need them, I need to pun them between <span>     </span>

Comment: you want to relace white spaces with **SPAN** tag ??

Comment: then simply you can use **str.replace** function to replace white space with **span** tag

Comment: no, I want to pun empty space between span...like so: <span>emptyspace</span>

Comment: I can do that, but only empty spaces within [a-z]. For numbers no

Answer (score 1):

```
text = text.replace(/\s+|(?:&nbsp;)+/g,function(x,i){
    if( text.charAt(i-1).match(/[a-zA-Z]/) == null && text.charAt(x.length+i).match(/[a-zA-Z]/) == null ){
        return '<span>'+x+'</span>';
    } else return x;
});
```

I`ve changed the rule, that white space should NOT match a-zA-Z

Comment: I see you made use of my approach of using a callback within a `replace`. If my answer was helpful, please consider at least upvoting my answer. It is not good when you change rules on the go without letting know of it. Still, it is good you found a solution yourself, thus +1.

Comment: there is no big rule, for match a-z, to not match...anyway, I did not had time to read all I saw your comment but for now I really need to focus on the solution so I`ll give your +1 then I`ll chose the best from all. Thanks

Comment: Well, after a year or so, have you made up your mind?